# Connecting PHP-informix-ubuntu 11.10

Tags: php, sql, ubuntu, informix, ubuntu-11.10

I am trying to configure PHP-informix environment on ubuntu 11.10.I am installed PDO and pdo_sqlite and soap but i can not install pdo_informix.I dont know what is the next step.

[image]

I got this screenshot when i check it on openadmin tool.i am stuck with this step.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for few days too but I eventually got it right. I used the below steps to create the connection to informix DB:

1. Make the PDO directory under root user.
2. Extract the `informix_pdo` file in the directory.
3. Enter the PDO Directory: `cd PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1/`.
4. Set your `INFORMIXDIR`:  `$ export INFORMIXDIR=/myifx/csdk`.
5. Execute `phpize`: `$ phpize`
6. Execute the configure:  `$ ./configure`.
7. Compile the PDO: `$ make`.
8. Install the PDO : `$ make install`.
9. Activate the PDO at PHP :

```
$ cd /etc/php5/conf.d
$ echo "extension=pdo_informix.so" > pdo_informix.ini
```

10. Restart apache.
11. Check the phpinfo to see if the informix_pdo extension is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

One likely problem is that the environment is not set correctly to find the Informix libraries that PDO_Informix uses.  You would normally need LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include $INFORMIXDIR/lib and $INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql.  As an alternative, you could use or edit the `ld.so.conf` file, perhaps.

You may find you need to set $INFORMIXDIR itself, and $INFORMIXSERVER too (or maybe instead).